# Is Azure Repos private repository "safe" to use?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

I am looking for a tool to create private repositories. I am using VS community 2019 and it integrates with azure repos easily. I enjoy the service and ease of use but I cannot find reliable information about Intellectual Property and "safety".

Is Azure Repos safe to use? Meaning - can I be quite confident that my code will not be stolen/visible in public? I have set the repository to private but I am not exactly sure if that is enough (I'm new to version control and repositories).

How about Intellectual Property? I have tried to find a concrete Microsoft statement about it but I did not succeed. Is the code stored on Azure Repos still mine? Can I be confident that the IP remains on my side?

I am using Azure Devops in free edition (for up to 5 users).
Thanks in advance for any information!

Comment: It's probably fine, but you could contact Microsoft's support if you have concerns. Anecdotally, Microsoft Azure Devops is very painful to work with, largely because historically, it's based on their Team Foundation Server (TFS) server with git support more recently added to it for strategic value. There are arguably much better options, such as GitHub (also Microsoft) or GitLab, both of which are also freeish, secure, and based at-core around git, which is largely considered to the most practical version control system. Mercurial or TFS may also make sense for your development practice.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it`s safe to use. You can find additional information here: [Data protection overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/data-protection?view=azure-devops).